# Profit-Loss Problems

Tags: percentages

> A dishonest merchant makes a 10% profit at the time of buying and a 5%
>   loss at the time of selling the goods he/she trades. By doing so if
>   the said merchant made a profit of $900 on a particular item, what was
>   the real cost of the item sold?

10% profit  book value # 110,,, then 5% loss on book value than selling price # 105.5. so profit # 4.5%. when 4.5% profit than cost 100,so when profit 900 than cost #(900*100)/4.5# 2000 tk? Can't be sure

Thanks in advance. Please Help me in solving this.

Comment: How can you make a profit when buying something?

Comment: I wondered about that too. This would require an objective value of the item. Like buying a $\$100$ itunes card for $\$90$.

Comment: Even then it's not clear wheter 10% profit means $B = 0.9 \cdot V$ or $1.1 \cdot B = V$ where $B$ is the buying price and $V$ said objective value.

Comment: I guess you have to assume some fixed price $k$ for the item. So he buys at $0.9k$ and sells at $0.95k$, giving a net profit of $0.05k=900$, so $k=1800$.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks Sir. I found the problem on facebook. It seemed awkward to me too.

Comment: @almagest Thank u so much Sir. I got the concept. It helped.

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution has few basic questions which should be clarified!!
If real cost price is 100  then with 10% it would be 110. But, if the case it is I think he loses because his price is higher than market price or real price. but in the question, it is said that he makes 10% profit at the time of buying. it is not the case of selling. it indicates that he buys the products with lower amount than the others. so

Let, 
Real cost price= 100.
cost of Dishonest merchant= 100- 100*10%= 90 
In the case of Selling, he loses 5%. that means, if everyone buys with 100 he buys with 100-100*5%= 95 
so his profit in two transaction= 95-90=5 
5=100
900=18000

Answer (score -1):

Let, cp=100x
his purchase price=90x (as 10% profit),
sp at a loss of 5%=95x,
now, sp-cp=profit,
95x-90x=900
x=180,
cp=100*180=18,000

Comment: You just repeat what has already been said.